# I'm having problems with understanding Object Orientation - java

Tags: java

I have been asked to create a class which simply prints "You have been registered".

In the second part, I am to create a test class. The test class should  create  two student instances (also called  objects). Then to print their names and call the    registered  method  of both of them. I keep getting errors saying 'the assignment to variable yearOfBirth has no effect' and in the test class 'The constructor String is undefined'.

Can you help with understanding the errors in my code.

```
public class Student{

//Attributes
private String name;
private String gender;
private int yearOfBirth;

//Constructors 
public Student (String name, String gender, int yearOfBirth){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth; // Default age of new student

}

public Student (String name, String gender){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.yearOfBirth = 0;
}

 //Getters & Setters

 public String getName() {
 return name; } 

 public void setName (String name) { 
 this.name = name; 
 }

 public String getGender () {
  return gender;
 }

 public void setGender (String gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
 }

public int getYearOfBirth() {
 return yearOfBirth;
}

public void setYearOfBirth() {
 if(yearOfBirth >= 0 && yearOfBirth <= 100) {
 this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;

}else {
    System.out.println("Age not valid");

}
}

//  Other Methods
public void Registered() { 
    System.out.println(name + "You have been registered");

 }

}


public class StudentTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student student1 =new Student("Kevin Sanches", "male", "1972");
    Student student2 = new Student("Cameron Young", "male", "1993");

    student1.Registered();
    student2.Registered();

    System.out.println(student1);
    System.out.println(student1);




}

}
```

Comment: Student student1 =new Student("Kevin Sanches", "male", 1972);
    Student student2 = new Student("Cameron Young", "male", 1993);

Comment: Not related to the errors you mention, but in `setYearOfBirth` method this test `if(yearOfBirth >= 0 && yearOfBirth <= 100)` might not do what you expect to do.  The test checks that the year of birth is between 0 and 100, it is not checking that the age of the student is between 0 and 100

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues in your code:

- *The assignment to variable yearOfBirth has no effect.* You are invoking a setter method on a property but you are not passing any value, hence the warning. You should provide a value as a parameter and set that to the corresponding object property.
- The constructor problem is that the age parameter is of type `int` instead when you construct the objects you are passing the age as string.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor expects two strings and an integer as parameters. You are passing three strings.

Correct way:

```
Student student1 =new Student("Kevin Sanches", "male", 1972);
Student student2 = new Student("Cameron Young", "male", 1993);
```

Also, in your method `setYearOfBirth` you forgot to pass the `yearOfBirth` as parameter.

```
public void setYearOfBirth(int yearOfBirth) {
    if(yearOfBirth >= 0 && yearOfBirth <= 100) {
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;

    }else {
        System.out.println("Age not valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send 3 `String`s which none of your constructors are ready to take. You have a constructor with 2 `String`s and an `int`, so the correct way of creating the object would be,

```
Student student1 = new Student("Kevin Sanches", "male", 1972);
```

Without the double quotes `1972` would be an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `this.yearOfBirth` to `this.yearOfbirth` in the setter. Even though code is just `this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;` technically both are `this.yearOfBirth` variables.

This needs to change by accepting the value and assigning it like:

```
public void setYearOfBirth(int yearOfBirth) {
 if(yearOfBirth >= 0 && yearOfBirth <= 100) {
 this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;

}else {
    System.out.println("Age not valid");

}
}
```

You are trying to pass a String value to the constructor that accepts int for the yearOfBirth value, change it like:

```
Student student1 =new Student("Kevin Sanches", "male", 1972);
Student student2 = new Student("Cameron Young", "male", 1993);
```